# Is there a test to determine whether a Diophantine equation has a solution in the positive integers?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there a test to determine whether the Diophantine equation,

$$ ax + by = z $$

with $a,x,b,y,z$ integers, $a >0, b>0, z>0$, has a solution with $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$?

In general we know that an integer solution exists if $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $z$. Can we tell if a non-negative integer solution exists?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Comment: Similar question recently asked: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518770/partition-number-of-ways-to-sum-two-positive-integers-into-constant

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple for the two-variable case.  Without loss of generality suppose $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ (else divide $a,b,z$ by that gcd, which gives an equivalent linear Diophantine equation with $x$ and $y$ exactly identical).

Now, using the Euclidean algorithm you can extract some (possibly negative) solution of $ax + by = z$, say $(x_0, y_0)$.  Every other solution necessarily has the form $(x_0 + bn, y_0 - an)$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$ (this is where we use the co-primality assumption).  In other words there is an integer solution for $x$ iff $x \equiv x_0 \pmod b$.  If we take $x_1$ to be the *smallest* positive residue of $x_0$ modulo $b$, and $y_1 := (z - ax_1)/b > 0$, then $(x_1,y_1)$ is a positive solution to $ax+by=z$.  Furthermore, it follows easily from monotonicity that this is also necessary: if $y_1 \le 0$ then there is no positive solution, because we'd need to increase $y$ and that would make $x$ nonpositive.